# Storing sourdough starters with wine in a wine fridge?

Tags: sourdough, wine, sourdough-starter

Specifically:

1. Can the yeast & carbon dioxide from the sourdough starter harm the wine bottles I'm aging in the refrigerator, and
2. Roughly how often would I have to feed the starter if stored only at 52 degrees F?

Thanks in advance for your input!

Answer (score 2):

My starter is going on 6+ years old now.  I keep it in the fridge in a covered container.  Of course, it would be slightly warmer in a wine fridge, but I would also recommend a covered container in that situation too.  There will be a little activity, but not enough for gas to escape.  In this scenario, I remove a portion of the starter, add new flour and water, and return to the fridge approximately weekly.  I have gone much longer between feedings with no harm...as long as I give it plenty of time to build up before use (at least a day on the counter...sometimes two if I've forgotten about it in the back of the fridge).  In any case, it will not impact your wine.

Comment: Thank you, moscafj! I have a number of natural wines from Burgundy that I plan to cellar for another 5-10 years, so I'm skittish when it comes to altering their environment. :)

Comment: @Liane763 I would be happy to "keep an eye" on your Burgundy wines if you are concerned.  ;-)  Would you like my shipping address?